# Android LinearLayout or RelativeLayout parent is useless?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my `Android` app, I have this `XML` file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    tools:context=".ActivityHome" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            style="@style/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
            android:onClick="CloseActivity"
            android:text="@+string/exit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_register"
            style="@style/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
            android:onClick="Register"
            android:text="@+string/register" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            style="@style/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
            android:onClick="OpenLoginScreen"
            android:text="@+string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And it's saying that the `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` is being useless..

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Now the buttons are top aligned, but need to be bottom aligned.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    tools:context=".ActivityHome" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            style="@style/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
            android:onClick="CloseActivity"
            android:text="@+string/exit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_register"
            style="@style/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
            android:onClick="Register"
            android:text="@+string/register" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            style="@style/footer"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
            android:onClick="OpenLoginScreen"
            android:text="@+string/login" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".ActivityHome" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="CloseActivity"
        android:text="@+string/exit" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="Register"
        android:text="@+string/register" />
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="OpenLoginScreen"
        android:text="@+string/login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will remove the unnecessary `RelativeLayout` and align your Views on the bottom of the Activity.

Comment: From your code, I added both `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`. You copied it right? I tested on my device and it showed the buttons bot aligned.

Comment: I changed `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` to `android:gravity="bottom"` then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not using them both right now. If for instance you add another linearLayout wrapper and have it positioned relative to the one above then you will be making use of them both.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityHome" 
   >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="CloseActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_exit"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="Register"
      />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_register"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="OpenLoginScreen"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove, the root parent "RelativeLayout" since you are practically not making use of it, the IDE is smart enough to tell when there's redundancy on the Layouts, you are actually doing nothing with the RelativeLayout other than Wrapping a LinearLayout hence a warning is shown, letting you know that its useless to have it...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
  tools:context=".ActivityHome" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="CloseActivity"
        android:text="@+string/exit"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_register"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="Register"
        android:text="@+string/register"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_footer"
        android:onClick="OpenLoginScreen"
        android:text="@+string/login" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Comment: I did this, but the buttons are top aligned. They need to be bottom aligned.

Comment: In that case, do not wrapp the elements on LinearLayout and in stead, align the last element on parent bottom, and the next element on top of it, and the next on top etc...